# Do I need a lead-free water hammer arrestor for washing machine?

Tags: lead, water-hammer

Our washing machine hammers really hard and shake pipes through the house. I've installed a few more supports for the pipes in the basement and that has helped, but it still hammers really hard and we want to quiet it down but also be sure that there is no damage being cause to the piping or the machine.

There is a [cheap option](https://www.supplyhouse.com/Sioux-Chief-660-H-Mini-Rester-Water-Hammer-Arrestor-3-4-F-Swivel-Hose-Thread-x-3-4-M-Hose-Thread-Tee) that might make sense to try first (I'll need two - hot and cold) that is *not lead safe*. At *4x the cost* of the above, the lead free option that I've found is to use a [hammer arrestor](https://www.supplyhouse.com/Sioux-Chief-652-A-Hydra-Rester-Commercial-Water-Hammer-Arrester-1-2-MIP-Thread) and [threaded fitting](https://www.supplyhouse.com/Watts-0121229-LF150HA-3-4-Lead-Free-Thread-for-1-2-Water-Hammer-Arrestor) together.

I don't plan on drinking water out of my washing machine, but my concern is that without a check valve between this and the rest of the piping. Is it best to go with lead free so as to prevent contaminated mixing back into the rest of the house?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are concerned about saving money, get the "not lead safe" one as this is a non-potable water installation.

If you are paranoid about lead and the remote possibility that a significant amount of lead could backflow from the cheaper arrester installation into your drinking water then spend the extra money on the lead-free certified product.

This is, in my opinion, an example of warnings gone awry where the actual danger is so remote as to be implausible.  I doubt that the less expensive product contains any lead at all but if you feel the need to be 100% certified then why are you quibbling about a few dollars?

Comment: I thought code required all components to be lead free connected to a residential water system. Many washers are on a dead end so I understand your point but code in my jurisdiction is for lead free on a residential system.

Comment: @EdBeal in that case the choice is moot.  If code requires certified lead-free for all fittings then regardless of the cost, a lead free arrester is required.

Comment: I was not sure if it was a local thing or not.

Comment: I guess this is the problem with people like me wanting to do easy upgrades without knowing the codes! for the extra $50, LF is probably just better all around I guess. And I suppose the fact that there (at least in some localities) codes requiring that all connected fittings be LF, suggests that my thinking was in the right direction, however low the risk or may not be.

Comment: "This is, in my opinion, an example of warnings gone awry where the actual danger is so remote as to be implausible" - yeah, who cares about anyone or anything downstream, as long as it doesn't affect you personally, pollute away?

Comment: @whatsisname A water hammer arrestor in your house, or any other component in your house, won't affect anyone else *outside your house*. But even in your own house, I'd be willing to bet the risk is so low as to be insignificant - a tiny part of the piping, the vast majority of the water (except into the washing machine) never flowing past it, very little lead actually leaching out *in general* - it takes a **lot** to make a significant (growth/brain affecting) amount, etc. But we live in a world of [Prop 65](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1986_California_Proposition_65) so, whatever.